# Unable to connect to Oracle DB in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

**Problem:**

If I use:

```
ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:5521/oracledb");
```

I get:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
not establish the connection
```

If I use:

```
ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:oci:localhost:5521:oracledb");
```

I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.t2cLogoff(J)I
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.t2cLogoff(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logoff(T2CConnection.java:664)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:697)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:54)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:241)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:184)
    ... 67 more
```

I'm using Oracle SQL 12c. I can use 'SQL developer' just fine with no issues. Where is the documentation that lists excactly what my connection setup will look like in java so I don't have to keep quessing at it? I've read tons of documentation that goes on and on about every little thing *except* how to know for sure that you will be using the right connection setup in Java.

Comment: can you try changing 5521 to 1521 and see if it works

Comment: That seemed to help. Now I get: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28000: the account is locked

Comment: I'm using HR hr as the username and password. The SQL server is running on the same machine as my java program

Comment: You need to unlock HR account. Login as SYS or SYSTEM, then run`ALTER USER HR ACCOUNT UNLOCK`. You can also do it using SQL-Developer - login as SYS or SYSTEM, find HR under `other users`, right click on HR, then choose EDIT, then find a checkbox named `lock user` (or similar - I don't remeber it's exact name), uncheck this checkbx an apply changes.

Comment: I unlocked the account but it is still unclear what the username and password needs to be to connect to the DB running locally

Comment: Give it a new password - `alter user hr identified by new-password`

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks!